# The Python kernel is unresponsive.The Python process exited with exit code 139 (SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault)

Tags: azure-databricks, mlflow

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEywo.png)

custom_vgg_model.save("/dbfs/FileStore/output/trained_model/my3_trained.h5")
when i ran this in databricks ,kernel crashed.But without '.h5' it worked.

I was expecting the trained model saved in filestore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even I got the same error while saving it in dbfs.

[image]

So follow below approach.

Save the model to local filesystem and load it in dbfs.

```
model.save('/tmp/my_models/my_model.h5')
```

[image]

```
dbutils.fs.ls("file:/tmp/my_models/")
```

[image]

copy the model to dbfs.

```
dbutils.fs.cp("file:/tmp/my_models/my_model.h5","dbfs:/tmp/my_models/my_model.h5")
```

[image]

Then load the model.

```
new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('/tmp/my_models/my_model.h5')
new_model.summary()
```

[image]